How to change rounding of the Android Material range sliders
I haven't found any information on how to change both the active and inactive tracks corner rounding for Android Material range sliders ; how do I do that or work around it?
I have read:

Android Developers RangeSlider reference
Material Components Discrete Slider documentation
Existing issues about track rounding in Material Components GitHub repository
Similar question but about the 2nd version of Material

